# mongodb Sharding with $nin sharded key

Tags: database, mongodb, sharding

I am new in sharding and i want to ask if you can shard a collection with a sharded key that will be used with $nin query.

For example let's say i have the collection:

```
{
      _id: ObjectId(...),
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Chalaris",
      role: "Manager",
      ....
}
```

If my sharded key is the role, is it possible to run efficiently the query:

```
db.users.find(role: {$nin: ["Manager, Support"]})
```

Answer (score 0):

[Shard Key](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/) plays an important part in distributing the data in cluster. It is also important that your query specifies the shard key as part of the filter criteria for efficiency.

The shard key values and chunks associated with them determine how many shards the query must visit. So, for performance the queries should include shard key as part filter criteria for a targeted operation (and avoid scatter-gather or broadcast) operation. `mongos` determines which shards to target.

Also, see: [Sharded Cluster Read Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/distributed-queries/#read-operations-to-sharded-clusters)

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's question.  His query does contain the shard key.  He's asking if using $nin in the query related to the shard key has an effect.